# Updating List Item from Solaris

Tags: 2010, oracle

I'm working on a project involving an Oracle team in a Solaris environment.  They need to be able to update a list item from their environment, programmatically.  I need to write a proof of concept that will update SharePoint from their environment.

What is the best way to interact with SharePoint from a UNIX environment?  PERL plays nicely with web services, right?  I'm thinking I can just access the SharePoint web services and attach the file with no problems from a PERL script.

Does anyone have any experience with this, and do you have any recommendations?  If there's a way to call an Oracle stored procedure to accomplish the same thing, that might be easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently [addressed a similar question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/46073/how-to-connect-an-ios-app-to-sharepoint-through-office-365/46078#46078) relating to iOS (which is still *nix).

You're best bet is to interface with the SharePoint web services. The web service to interface with lists is http://the.url.to.the.site/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx.

It would be interesting to see how you finally manage this task. There is a .NET implementation of properties and methods of the web service [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvclists.lists_members.aspx), but since you are calling from *nix, I would assume you have to understand and recreate the SOAP calls (unless you can make it work in Mono C#).